# How to iterate through nested dictionary and modify the values for respective keys by passing list items?

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I am having this dictionary :

my_dict = { "id": 0,"forGroup": {"forGroupName": "NewApi_69192", "nId": 69192,"nText": "textNewApi_69192" },"notif": { "fmNotif": "true", "emailNotif": []} }

I want to create new dictionaries by modifying the values of forGroupName, nId and nText through a list.

Example :

I have created three lists lst2,lst,lst3 for the values which needs to be changed corresponding to the keys forGroupName ,nId ,nText

```
lst2 =[]
lst3 = []

lst = [i for i in range(69190,69192+1)]

for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst2.append("NewApi_"+ str(lst[i]))

for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst3.append("textNewApi_"+ str(lst[i]))
 
output:

[69190, 69191, 69192, 69193]
['NewApi_69190', 'NewApi_69191', 'NewApi_69192', 'NewApi_69193']
['textNewApi_69190', 'textNewApi_69191', 'textNewApi_69192', 'textNewApi_69193']
```

In this way it should create four dictionaries :

```
my_dict0 = { "id": 0,"forGroup": {"forGroupName": "NewApi_69190", "nId": 69190,"nText": "textNewApi_69190" },"notif": { "fmNotif": "true", "emailNotif": []} }
my_dict1 = { "id": 0,"forGroup": {"forGroupName": "NewApi_69191", "nId": 69191,"nText": "textNewApi_69191" },"notif": { "fmNotif": "true", "emailNotif": []} }
my_dict2 = { "id": 0,"forGroup": {"forGroupName": "NewApi_69192", "nId": 69192,"nText": "textNewApi_69192" },"notif": { "fmNotif": "true", "emailNotif": []} }
my_dict3 = { "id": 0,"forGroup": {"forGroupName": "NewApi_69193", "nId": 69193,"nText": "textNewApi_69193" },"notif": { "fmNotif": "true", "emailNotif": []} }
```

I have written some demo code which is not working correct and also only for one key is changed . How to change for all three and create a new dictionary every time.

```
for val in my_dict.values():
    if isinstance(val, dict):
        for key, value in val.items():
            print(key,':',value)
            if key == 'forGroupName':
                for x in range(len(lst2)):  
                    val[key] = lst2[x]
                    print('after chnages', val)
```

could anyone suggest a optimal solution to this ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, or the approach you're taking. Can you please elaborate.

This will create 4 dictionaries that are the same as your `my_dict0`, `my_dict1`, `my_dict2`, `my_dict3`.

```py
dicts = []

for i in range(69190, 69194):
    d = {
        "id": 0,
        "forGroup": {
            "forGroupName": f"NewApi_{i}",
            "nId": i,
            "nText": f"textNewApi_{i}"
        },
        "notif": {
            "fmNotif": "true",
            "emailNotif": [],
        }
    }
    
    dicts.append(d)

my_dict0, my_dict1, my_dict2, my_dict3 = dicts
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordan , Actually my original dictionary was too big so could not post here complete and moreover after parsing that dict I was trying to replace the above mentioned values from the respective lists. But Thanks your approach is much better than what I was trying . It changes the values at single place rather than creating separate lists. But  I think I was to ask like the dicts in your code is returning a list of all the values . so how could I take them in separate dictionaries?

Comment: They _are_ separate dictionaries. The separate dictionaries are stored in the list `dicts`. The last line unpacks this list into 4 variables: `my_dict0, my_dict1, my_dict2, my_dict3`. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: ok Thanks for the hint. I will try the similar way to achieve my results. 
I am not sure how to elaborate it more like I have given the details from my end on what to be done here.